# how to add protoc.exe in path of windows 7

Tags: windows, maven, path, protoc

I tried Following :

1.D:\TestWorkSpace\protoc.exe where .exe file is residing.

Method1

```
      1.PROTO_HOME = "D:\TestWorkSpace\"
      2.Path = "%PROTO_HOME%\protoc.exe"
```

Method2

```
      1.PROTO_HOME = "D:\TestWorkSpace\"
      2.Path = "%PROTO_HOME%\protoc"
```

but still unable to add protoc.exe in class path.
I am using a project in which maven project is to be imported , before development , and pre-requisite is to add protoc.exe in class path.

Kindly provide your valuable suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to add protoc to the "PATH", not to the classpath?!

use:

```
  PROTO_HOME = "D:\TestWorkSpace\"
  2.Path = "%PROTO_HOME%"
```

And you are able to call protoc.exe without path